# getting this error message Error during LWC component

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

getting this error message

> **Error during LWC component connect phase: [Cannot read property**
> **'objectApiName' of undefined]**

while trying to put the LWC component to the page

```java
import { LightningElement,track,api } from 'lwc';
import getTime from '@salesforce/apex/BookingTimeByDate.getTime';
export default class Sitelandingpage extends LightningElement {
    @track accounts; 
    @track choosenDate;
   @track DE1_ED1__Service_Request__c;
    handledateselect(event){
        this.choosenDate=event.target.value;
        getTime({TimebyDate: this.choosenDate})
        .then(data => {
            this.DE1_ED1__Service_Request__c = data;
            console.log(data);
        })
       }
}
```

Comment: Hi @DiV can you post the code you are trying to execute? It looks like an error where your object is not defined and you are attempting to retrieve a property from it.

Comment: Would you also include and take a look at your LWC's metadata file (.js-meta.xml)? It's possible, since the issue is happening when you place the component on your page, that there is a problem with one of your component properties.

Comment: I had the same error when I had a typo in iconName attribute (e.g. standard:account) of the lightning:card component. Fixing the typo got rid of that message